# How do I override a template on readthedocs?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I recently added [sphinx documentation for blowdrycss](http://blowdrycss.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to readthedocs.

I want to override the layout.html template on [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/). My current template override works fine on `localhost`, but not on readthedocs. The project uses the Alabaster theme which extends the basic theme.

Project directory structure can be seen [here](https://github.com/nueverest/blowdrycss/tree/master/docs)

**The relevant parts are:**

```
blowdrycss/
    docs/
        _templates/
            layout.html

        conf.py
```

**Template setting in `conf.py`:**

```
templates_path = ['_templates']
```

**Contents of layout.html:**

```
{% extends '!layout.html' %}


{% block sidebarsearch %}
    {{ super() }}
    <a href="https://flattr.com/submit/auto?user_id=nueverest&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnueverest%2Fblowdrycss" target="_blank"><img src="http://button.flattr.com/flattr-badge-large.png" alt="Flattr this" title="Flattr this" border="0"></a>
{% endblock %}


{% block footer %}
    <div class="footer" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://flattr.com/submit/auto?user_id=nueverest&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnueverest%2Fblowdrycss" target="_blank"><img src="http://button.flattr.com/flattr-badge-large.png" alt="Flattr this" title="Flattr this" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

How do I override the `layout.html` template on readthedocs?

**Update**
I've also tried:

**The relevant parts are:**

```
blowdrycss/
    docs/
        custom_templates/
            layout.html

        conf.py
```

**Template setting in `conf.py`:**

```
templates_path = ['custom_templates']
```

Comment: *_templates* is the default one, can you try with another one?

Comment: i created a new directory `custom_templates` and place `layout.html` inside readthedocs still does not recognize it.

Comment: It's actually documented on read-the-docs http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/theme.html

Comment: @Wolph I'm using the Alabaster theme not the rtd theme.

Comment: @nueverest: I was referring to this bit: "By default, Read the Docs will use its own custom sphinx theme unless you set one yourself in your `conf.py` file."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While readthedocs doesn't support the `templates_path` straight away, you can use a custom theme with templates inside of it. http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html

Simply create a new theme directory and add this to your `conf.py`:

```
html_theme = 'your_theme'
html_theme_path = ['.']
```

You can see an example in one of my projects:

- http://django-utils2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- https://github.com/WoLpH/django-utils/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L109-L117

Comment: I used `html_theme_path = ['custom_themes', ]` copied and pasted the alabaster theme into it renamed it to `custom_alabaster` and edited the template files. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like now ReadTheDocs *should* support `templates_path`: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/remove-edit-buttons.html?highlight=templates_path#remove-links-from-top-right-corner